# Sharekit is authorizing but not sharing

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, sharekit

I know there are a lot of topics on this issue, but I just can't figure out what is wrong.

I want to implement sharekit for Facebook and Twitter, so I followed the install instructions on the github:

Appid is set, got my entry in the cfurlschemes thingy, etc.

I authorize my app:

```
- (void)authorizeFacebook {
    [self.facebook authorize];
}
```

(self.facebook is a strong member of a share controller singleton).

To share:

```
- (void)shareFacebook:(SHKItem*)toShare {
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:toShare];
}
```

I also tried:

```
- (void)shareFacebook:(SHKItem*)toShare {
    [self.facebook setItem:toShare];
    [self.facebook share];
}
```

The same constructions are made for twitter.

I can authorize my apps without issue, so my configuration should be fine. When I authorize my app before i call the shareFacebook function, it is authorized but nothing happens with the sharing. 
When I don't auhorize before calling shareFacebook (so sharekit detects it is not authorizes and opens authorization first) the'sharekitSendDidFinish' notification is fired but nothing appears on Facebook.

The same goes for Twitter, authorization works but no tweets appear. The SHKItem i'm trying to share is not nil and is filled with the correct stuff I need to share.

*Edit
I'm trying to share an SHKItem with:
Title
Text
Image

- I also tried to send an SHKItem with just text, but that didn't work either.
- Reinstalling ShareKit did nothing.
- Failed with error is not being fired
- Senddidfinish is being fired (but only if you authorize via the share function) and has no 'last error'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I forgot to set the sharetype... stupid that it doesnt give an error for this :S

Comment: Please explain a little more. I am also stuck at this problem.